# How to subtract every element from one array to another?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, math

I have got two arrays of equal size.

```
double[] array1;
double[] array2; //array1 size == array2 size
```

I have also got a constant number `double constant  = 5`. Say 5 for example
I want to create a new array `double[] array3;` where we take every element in array1 and subtract the element at the same index in array2 from array1.
So that:

`array3[i] = array1[i] - array2[i]`

I then want to subtract the constant to all elements in array3 thereafter.

I can do this all with a for loop however my arrays are massive so it takes a very long time to compute. Is there a way to do the subtraction specifically without using for loops?

example data:

if:

```
array1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
array2 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
```

then

```
array3 = {0.9, 1.8, 2.7, 3.6, 4.5, 5.4}
```

now subtract `constant`

```
array3 = {-4.1, -3.2, -2.3, - 1.4, -0.5, 0.4}
```

Comment: You can do `array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => x - y)`, but that won't necessarily be quicker than a `for` loop...

Comment: _" Is there a way to do the subtraction specifically without using for loops?"_ - Somewhere you're going to need to loop over the arrays - at least once.

Comment: As said above, even if you don't *explicitly* use a `for` loop, you'll end up looping through your arrays (potentially *internally* but still)

Comment: if `array1` and `array2` are the same size you could use 1 `for` loop only. `for(int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++) { array3[i] = (array1[i] - array2[i]) - const); }`, I don't see any reason you can't do all the operations in one iteration, subtract the array values, and the const in each iteration.

Comment: There is a [Parallel.For Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-5.0); however, it will speed up things only if the amount of work to perform is substantial. And there are also [SIMD-accelerated types in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/simd#how-to-use-simd).

Comment: How big are these vectors? For just above small size I found the loop unrolling helps a bit, but not much.

Comment: You can use a BLAS wrapper in C# to get the best speed possible. Or you can write a Fortran or C++ dll to call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really no avoiding having to loop over the arrays at least once, but there is the built-in LINQ `Zip` method which does most of the hard work for you.

The thing to *NOT* do is loop more than necessary so dont subtract the constant value after doing the initial subraction - do it at the same time

```
var array1 = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var array2 = new[]{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
var constant = 5;
var array3 = array1.Zip(array2, (x,y) => x-y-constant).ToArray();
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/An8IuE

This will ultimately be a little slower than a simple for loop

```
var array1 = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var array2 = new[]{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
var constant = 5;
var array3 = new double[array1.Length];
for(int i=0,j=array1.Length; i<j;i++)
    array3[i] = array1[i] - array2[i] - constant;
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r5JQKN

Answer (score 3):

If the order doesn't actually matter, then you can use `AsParallel` to parallelize your `Zip` using PLINQ:

```
var array1 = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
var array2 = new[]{0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6};
var constant = 5;
var array3 = array1.AsParallel().Zip(array2.AsParallel(), (x,y) => x-y-constant);
```

Because it happens in parallel, the results will be out of order (but will still be correct).

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5xhfP3)

#### Edit:

Whether the parallel one will be faster than the sequential one depends on your hardware and input size. For me, a lot of the online compilers (rextester, C# fiddle) showed the sequential execution to be faster (most likely because their resources are limited and input size couldn't be too large), On my local machine, I was able to see the parallel execution become faster as the input size approached ~10 million elements per array. The takeaway for you is "Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark"

Answer (score 2):

```cs
Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length).Select(x => array1[x] - array2[x] + constant);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [overload of Enumerable.Zip that has a parameter resultSelector](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

```
double[] array1 = ...;
double[] array2 = ...;
const double value = 5.0;

var result = array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => x - y - value);
```